# Jquery form sorting while changing the id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am creating a survey app. Once the user proceeds to create the survey, they can dynamically add multiple questions by clicking on the add question button. I have added a sortable option(with a handle) using the jquery ui. Once a user sorts the question how do i change the id on the form.

```
<div class="question" id="1"></div>
<div class="question" id="2"></div>
```

Or is there any way to capture the position since i want to print it out in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stop callback of your sortable widget, reassign your id like this :

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    stop : function ( event, ui ){
        $('.question').each(function(index){
            $(this).attr('id',index);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to remove the `id` and re-add in order you could do:

```
$('.question').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', index);
});
```

This will loop through all `.question` elements and base the `id` on their list order.

P.S. `id` should begin with an alphabetic [A-Za-z] character.